# Making use of gcloud credentials (which was setup in host OS) within docker container

Tags: docker, gcloud, bamboo, google-cloud-sdk

I've been trying to run containerized build in Bamboo with Docker. The reason behind is that some other dependencies in the agent are outdated (i.e: NodeJS) and I wish to have a controlled configuration.

Since all Bamboo build agents in our company had been configured with gcloud service account credentials, I wanted to make use of those credentials within the Docker container.

After doing some research, I understood that gcloud credentials are stored at `~/.config/gcloud`.

Hence, during container creation, I supplied the following volume mount:

```
docker run --volume /home/bamboo/.config/gcloud:/root/.config/gcloud --detach --name POC google/cloud-sdk:340.0.0-slim
```

with that, I'm able to see the files are appearing correctly within the Docker container.

```
build   03-Feb-2022 09:42:22    /root/.config/gcloud
build   03-Feb-2022 09:42:22    total 48
build   03-Feb-2022 09:42:22    drwx------  4 1004 1004 4096 Nov 20  2020 .
build   03-Feb-2022 09:42:22    drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Feb  3 09:42 ..
build   03-Feb-2022 09:42:22    -rw-------  1 1004 1004 3072 Oct 29  2020 access_tokens.db
build   03-Feb-2022 09:42:22    -rw-rw-r--  1 1004 1004    7 Apr 19  2017 active_config
build   03-Feb-2022 09:42:22    -rw-rw-r--  1 1004 1004    0 May 25  2021 config_sentinel
build   03-Feb-2022 09:42:22    drwxrwxr-x  2 1004 1004 4096 Apr 19  2017 configurations
build   03-Feb-2022 09:42:22    -rw-------  1 1004 1004 3072 Nov  7  2017 credentials.db
build   03-Feb-2022 09:42:22    -rw-------  1 1004 1004    5 Feb  3 08:30 gce
build   03-Feb-2022 09:42:22    -rw-rw-r--  1 1004 1004   37 Nov 20  2020 .last_opt_in_prompt.yaml
build   03-Feb-2022 09:42:22    -rw-r--r--  1 1004 1004   37 May 21  2021 .last_survey_prompt.yaml
build   03-Feb-2022 09:42:22    -rw-rw-r--  1 1004 1004  273 Sep 30  2017 .last_update_check.json
build   03-Feb-2022 09:42:22    drwxrwxr-x 27 1004 1004 4096 Feb  3 08:30 logs
build   03-Feb-2022 09:42:22    -rw-rw-r--  1 1004 1004   32 Apr 19  2017 .metricsUUID
```

However, when I perform the command `gcloud auth list`, it gives the following error:

```
error   03-Feb-2022 09:50:56    No credentialed accounts.
error   03-Feb-2022 09:50:56    
error   03-Feb-2022 09:50:56    To login, run:
error   03-Feb-2022 09:50:56      $ gcloud auth login `ACCOUNT`
```

Invoking the same command within the agent returns authenticated account list correctly.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I recommend using a volume mount to the service account JSON key file and then **gcloud auth activate-service-account**. I do not recommend manipulating or accessing the internal CLI files.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need to `auth/credential_file_override` to reference your Service Account.

See the [usage instructions(https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk) in the repository that you're using:

```sh
docker run \
--interactive --tty \
--env=CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=/config/mygcloud \
--volume=${PWD}/mygcloud:/config/mygcloud \
--volume=${PWD}:/certs \
google/cloud-sdk:alpine \
  /bin/bash

gcloud config list
[auth]
credential_file_override = /certs/svc_account.json

more /certs/svc_account.json
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project_id",
....
}
```